# Apply formatting after string formatting

Tags: python

I don't know if it's possible with common string formatting or advanced string formatting, so thought to ask...

I have this simplified snippet:

```
>>> s = 'some string'
>>> y = 10
>>> '<td>%s</td><td>%4d</td>' % (s, y)
'<td>some string</td><td>  10</td>'
```

I want to pad numeric cell with `&nbsp;` as my html backend doesn't accept text aligning.
Is there easy way to format numerical value with `&nbsp;` instead empty space?

Comment: I'm no HTML wizard, but it seems to me that using spaces for alignment is a questionable tactic.

Comment: It's a Qt widget, and this desperate tactic is only that works, without digging why is it like that as I want to display just content. Now it looks great BTW, I can't stand left aligned numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
"%s%d" % ("&nbsp;" * (4 - len(str(y))), y)
```

Comment: Good idea, haven't thought about it. Thanks

Comment: +1 for a simple, practical answer, but I can't help but wonder if the OP is well served using spaces to align (right justify?) data in an HTML table.